# OpenEdge database connection issue

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

Im trying to add another data in a from table in a separate database to my script, 
but I keep getting this error all time.

My script

```
connect database "chris.db" .
```

run chrisf.p 
disconnect databse.

The error I'm getting

[image]

How can I get round this issue?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word "database" is not part of the syntax for the CONNECT statement.

```
CONNECT "chris".
```

is the correct syntax.

The OpenEdge documentation for CONNECT is here:  https://documentation.progress.com/output/OpenEdge117/openedge117/?_ga=2.93982683.75218856.1547464117-1040589272.1546786181#page/dvpin%2Fthe-connect-statement.html

I'm not sure what you are trying to do with:

```
run chrisf.p disconnect databse.
```

but that will run an external procedure called "chrisf.p" and pass 2 "compile on the fly" parameters with values of "disconnect" and "databse".  (I'm pretty sure that's not really what you intend.)

Comment: Thank you for the support, That worked perfect. I thought , I had to Include the word database .